# SQL Server 2008 - Advanced Search/Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting, full-text-search

I need to conduct a search on a column and sort the results in a specific order. The search criteria and the sort order is going to be as following:

At least 'x' and at most all of the characters for a given search text must be matched. Result should be grouped by begins with (then sort by number of characters matched) followed by contains (then sort by number of characters matched and alphabetically).

For Example:

Search Text: **Alliance A**

**Values in Database:**

[image]

The search results should appear in the following order

[image]

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Here an algorithm implementation for T-SQL: [Calculating Levenshtein Distance in TSQL](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/calculating-levenshtein-distance-in-tsql/)

As function signature is like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN]( @s NVARCHAR(MAX), @t NVARCHAR(MAX) )
/*
Levenshtein Distance Algorithm: TSQL Implementation
by Joseph Gama

http://www.merriampark.com/ldtsql.htm
```

You can invoke it in your query as:

```
Select *
from ValuesInDatabase V
order by
    [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN](  V.ClientName, 'Alliance A' )
```

You don't should expect high performance.

**Edited**

I copy here Joseph Gama's function to preserve it, don't forget visit [devioblog](http://devio.wordpress.com/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN]( @s NVARCHAR(MAX), @t NVARCHAR(MAX) )
/*
Levenshtein Distance Algorithm: TSQL Implementation
by Joseph Gama

http://www.merriampark.com/ldtsql.htm

Returns the Levenshtein Distance between strings s1 and s2.
Original developer: Michael Gilleland http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm
Translated to TSQL by Joseph Gama

Fixed by Herbert Oppolzer / devio
as described in http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/calculating-levenshtein-distance-in-tsql
*/
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @d NVARCHAR(MAX), @LD INT, @m INT, @n INT, @i INT, @j INT,
    @s_i NCHAR(1), @t_j NCHAR(1),@cost INT

  --Step 1
  SET @n = LEN(@s)
  SET @m = LEN(@t)
  SET @d = REPLICATE(NCHAR(0),(@n+1)*(@m+1))
  IF @n = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @LD = @m
   GOTO done
  END
  IF @m = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @LD = @n
    GOTO done
  END

  --Step 2
  SET @i = 0
  WHILE @i <= @n BEGIN
    SET @d = STUFF(@d,@i+1,1,NCHAR(@i))        --d(i, 0) = i
    SET @i = @i+1
  END

  SET @i = 0
  WHILE @i <= @m BEGIN
    SET @d = STUFF(@d,@i*(@n+1)+1,1,NCHAR(@i))    --d(0, j) = j
    SET @i = @i+1
  END

  --Step 3
  SET @i = 1
  WHILE @i <= @n BEGIN
    SET @s_i = SUBSTRING(@s,@i,1)

    --Step 4
    SET @j = 1
    WHILE @j <= @m BEGIN
      SET @t_j = SUBSTRING(@t,@j,1)
      --Step 5
      IF @s_i = @t_j
        SET @cost = 0
      ELSE
        SET @cost = 1
      --Step 6
      SET @d = STUFF(@d,@j*(@n+1)+@i+1,1,
        NCHAR(dbo.MIN3(
          UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@d,@j*(@n+1)+@i-1+1,1))+1,
          UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@d,(@j-1)*(@n+1)+@i+1,1))+1,
          UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@d,(@j-1)*(@n+1)+@i-1+1,1))+@cost)
        ))
      SET @j = @j+1
    END
    SET @i = @i+1
  END      

  --Step 7
  SET @LD = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@d,@n*(@m+1)+@m+1,1))

done:
  RETURN @LD
END
```